# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1}'")

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am following along this [Python Flask From Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Us9DuF4KWUE&t=1s), I am now on the section of editing and delete of posts. I have followed the tutorial throughly and even copied the solution code as a replacement of the code i've written to see if I had an error, but I continue to receive error message

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1}'")

I've identified this code to be the problem since the program was working find before I added the edit_article section.

```
 # Edit Article
@app.route('/edit_article/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def edit_article(id):
    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    # Get article by id
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = %s", [id])

    article = cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()
    # Get form
    form = ArticleForm(request.form)

    # Populate article form fields
    form.title.data = article['title']
    form.body.data = article['body']

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']

        # Create Cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        app.logger.info(title)
        # Execute
        cur.execute ("UPDATE articles SET title=%s, body=%s WHERE id=%s",(title, body, id))
        # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        #Close connection
        cur.close()

        flash('Article Updated', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('edit_article.html', form=form)
```

complete code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, logging, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

# Config MySQL
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '***************'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'myflaskapp'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'

# init MySQL
mysql = MySQL(app)


# Index
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


# About
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


# Articles
@app.route('/articles')
def articles():
    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    # Get articles
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles")

    articles = cur.fetchall()

    if result > 0:
        return render_template('articles.html', articles=articles)
    else:
        msg = 'No Articles Found'
        return render_template('articles.html', msg=msg)

    # Close connection
    cur.close()


# Single Article
@app.route('/article/<string:id>/')
def article(id):
    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    # Get article
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = %s", [id])

    article = cur.fetchone()

    return render_template('article.html', article=article)


# Register Form Class
class RegisterForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', [validators.Length(min=1, max=50)])
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=50)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords do not match')
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')


# Register
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        username = form.username.data
        password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))

        # Create cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        # Execute query
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))

        # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        cur.close()

        flash('You are now registered and can log in', 'positive')

        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)


# User Login
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get Form Fields
        username = request.form['username']
        password_candidate = request.form['password']

        # Create cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        # Get User by username
        result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])

        if result > 0:
            # Get stored hash
            data = cur.fetchone()
            password = data['password']

            # Compare passwords
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password_candidate, password):
                # Passed
                session['logged_in'] = True
                session['username'] = username

                flash('You are now logged in', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

            else:
                error = 'Invalid login'
                return render_template('login.html', error=error)
            # Close connection
            cur.close()
        else:
            error = 'Username not found'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)

    return render_template('login.html')


# Check if user logged in / unauthorized
def is_logged_in(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('Unauthorized, Please login', 'negative')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap


# Logout
@app.route('/logout')
@is_logged_in
def logout():
    session.clear()
    flash('You are now logged out', 'positive')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


# Dashboard
@app.route('/dashboard')
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():

    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    # Get articles
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles")

    articles = cur.fetchall()

    if result > 0:
        return render_template('dashboard.html', articles=articles)
    else:
        msg = 'No Articles Found'
        return render_template('dashboard.html', msg=msg)

    # Close connection
    cur.close()


# Article Form Class
class ArticleForm(Form):
    title = StringField('Title', [validators.Length(min=1, max=200)])
    body = TextAreaField('Body', [validators.Length(min=30)])


# Add Article
@app.route('/add_article', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def add_article():
    form = ArticleForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        title = form.title.data
        body = form.body.data

        # Create Cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        # Execute
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO articles(title, body, author) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", (title, body, session['username']))

        # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        # Close Connection
        cur.close()

        flash('Article Created', 'positive')

        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('add_article.html', form=form)


# Edit Article
@app.route('/edit_article/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def edit_article(id):
    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    # Get article by id
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = %s", [id])

    article = cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()
    # Get form
    form = ArticleForm(request.form)

    # Populate article form fields
    form.title.data = article['title']
    form.body.data = article['body']

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']

        # Create Cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        app.logger.info(title)
        # Execute
        cur.execute ("UPDATE articles SET title=%s, body=%s WHERE id=%s",(title, body, id))
        # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        #Close connection
        cur.close()

        flash('Article Updated', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('edit_article.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'secret123'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

On cursory glance, it looks like the error is occurring here:

```
cur.execute ("UPDATE articles SET title=%s, body=%s WHERE id=%s",(title, body, id))
```

Problem 1) id isn't defined up with title and body:

```
    title = request.form['title']
    body = request.form['body']
```

Problem 2) If id is numeric, you need to format into your 'execute' string with %d.

```
cur.execute ("UPDATE articles SET title=%s, body=%s WHERE id=%d",(title, body, id))
```

Comment: Joshua - thank you for your response. id is a string, when i attempt to change it to a decimal i receive the following error "_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: %d format: a number is required, not str"

Comment: Ah, I see. I also see now where id is a parameter. Did a poor cursory glance!

Comment: Any idea why this isn't working? The author of the tutorial got the app working without issue but when i copy and paste his code it doesn't work..